# How to make a lens with zoomed effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects, zoom

How do I go about creating this effect in Photoshop cs6?

[image]

**Don't forget to mark this question as useful :)**

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to GD.SE :) The effect looks like an overlay with a zoomed in layer and a white stroke. It would help if you tell us what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Yisela .I am a newbie in Photoshop, I have researched all over the internet but found only the zoom effect not the lens having the zoom effect. I am in need of a step-by-step of how to go about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I would go about it. You will need an image in good resolution (as big as the zoomed part). Pardon my very simple samples, I hope you can get the idea anyway!

- Open the image. Make a round selection of the part you will want zoomed in using the `Elliptical Marquee Tool`.
  [image]
- Once you have your circle selected, copy and paste in a new layer (one way is to use right click on the selection, then `Layer Via Copy`).
- In a new document -or using the same one-, resize your original image so the background looks 'smaller'. Keep your circular selection layer in the original size (**don't** use `Image > Image Size`, instead use `Free Transform`).
  [image]
- Add a 5px (more or less) white stroke to the circular shape using `Blending Options > Stroke`.
- Add a 90 degrees shadow (going up-down) using `Blending Options > Drop Shadow`. [image]

You can add more effects to make the lense look a little more realistic. For example, you could use the Warp Tool (`Edit > Transform > Warp`) to make the circle more 'bloated', or you could also add a darker Inner Shadow (in the layer, `Blending Options > Inner Shadow`).

Comment: What about doing the `Free Transform` on the initial document, get `Elliptical Marquee Tool` to the part then follow the rest of the steps you have put?

Comment: @Ng'esh It's good as long as you have a higher resolution image to take the zoom image from. If you first resize then you'll loose the quality to take a larger sample for the circle.